# Heroku : Application Error When I try to load the page [Node.js + Express]

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

index.js

```
// create an express app
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// use the express-static middleware
app.use(express.static("public"));

// define the first route
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
});
  
// start the server listening for requests
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log("Server is running..."));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "SimpleApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x",
    "npm": "*"
  }
}
```

Procfile

```
web: echo "I don't want a web process"
service: npm start
```

I have deployed it in heroku.

And the logs are showing as below

```
2021-06-22T13:16:11.346614+00:00 app[service.1]: ------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-06-22T13:16:11.371025+00:00 app[service.1]: Server is running...
```

**But i am getting application error when i try to load the page.**

**It is working fine in local**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Your web dyno maybe turned off by default.You need to turn it on inorder to run your heroku app**

Answer (score 0):

**When declaring the middleware check whether that directory you have set is correct**

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

If not then use __dirname to concatinate the correct directory like so

`const public = path.join(__dirname, "../public")`

then

`app.use(express.static(public));`